# How to return to row from Object.keys(1Darray) in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, json, api

This codes get Json data from API of exchanges,

Everything goes well but I couldnt handle one thing

This part of my codes is get symbols to colums, but I want them to rows

```js
var url= "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=all&depth=1";
var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());

var headerRow= Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parcedData)
var header = [];
  header.push(headerRow);
  binance.getRange(binance.getLastRow()+1, 5, header.length, 99).setValues(header);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKtCw.jpg)

how can I fix it?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to know how to help you without seeing what is inside "header" array (since we dont what "binance" object is). Is it another array, string (if so which format - CSV, JSON,...) ? 
Please console.log(header) array so we can help you make symbols in rows

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the end result should look like?

Comment: @Tanaike's solution is work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to import the values to a row using `setValues()`, please modify from `[[A, B, C,,,]]` to `[[A], [B], [C],,,]`. So how about this modification?

#### From :

```
var header = [];
header.push(headerRow);
```

#### To :

```
var header = headerRow.map(function(e){return [e]});
```

#### Note :

- In your script, I couldn't find about `binance`. But I think that from your image, you can import the values using `setValues()`.

  - If the values cannot be imported using `setValues()`, please tell me.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Now I need to find how to separate from BTC_XMR in a cell to BTC and XMR different cell, can you help that also?

Comment: @TUFAN POYRAZ Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. For your next question, can you post it as a new question? Although I would like to solve your issue, I couldn't understand what you want to do from your comment. So when you post it with the detail information, we will be able to think of your solution. If this proposal is what you don't want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parcedData)
```

is the problem. The object property names are references to what you want each row to contain rather than header rows. It appears you want these data in each row (these are the columns):

- asks
- bids
- isFroze
- sequence

If this is correct, to achieve this you will do ( in pseudo):

```
let rows = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parcedData);
// put new TR open tag here
for(row in rows){
  row.asks <-- into a TD
  row.bids  <-- into a TD
  row.isFrozen  <-- into a TD
  row.sequence  <-- into a TD
 }
 // put TR close here
```

Comment: thanks but before your solution I tried @Tanaike's solution and it worked

Comment: glad you got it sorted out.